# Unable to delete comment using Facebook Javascript SDK - use right access-token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I'm trying to delete a comment using a Graph API call.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[comment-id]?access_token=[access-token]&method=delete
```

However, in terms of access-token, I'm not sure which one to use? I have used my App's "User Access Token", "Page Access Token" and "App Token". It doesn't work for any of these.

[PS, my app has all permissions, and I have even submitted it for review]

I just wanted to know if it was even possible to delete a comment which was not posted by the application? (Because I see that Delete is only allowed for page access tokens).

So, please do let me know if it is possible to delete a comment from a user's posts. And if so, which access_token to provide.

Answer (score 0):

The docs list all the neccessary Access Tokens and permissions:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/comment#deleting

I tried it with a user profile, it does not seem to be possible to post comments or delete them - no matter if was created by the App or manually:

> Publishing comments through the API is only available for page access
>   tokens

For Pages, you need to use a Page Tokens with the neccessary permissions according to the docs.

Comment: So, is it not possible to delete the posts of a particular user?

Comment: And we can only delete the comments/posts of a particular page?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you're doing an HTTP GET call and just putting &method=delete at the end. That's not how it works

You should do an HTTP DELETE call. So instead of doing something like $.get(...), you should do [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with `type: 'DELETE'`

Also, make sure your token has `publish_actions` permission

Comment: I'm trying to do this on the graph API explorer of facebook. (developer.facebook.com/tools/explore) and I get the invalid access token issue for a post.